# How to pass and catch variable when the method is POST then the route is GET?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a web application, and I want to pass variable called ID when the form method is `post` that linked to open other form but in the `config/routes` I'm using `$routes[page_A][get] = 'Controller'` not `$routes[page_A][post] = 'Controller'`.

I'm using Codeigniter framework here, I've tried to change the controller with `$this->input->get('id')` but it doesn't work and I don't have any idea whats really happen in my codes.

**The Sender Form View code**

```
<form action="<?= base_url().'progres_save'; ?>" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="idJobOrder">ID Job Order</label>
        <input type="text" name="idJobOrder" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $rd[0]->kodejobglobal; ?>" readonly>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
       <a class="btn btn-primary col-xl-1 col-sm-1 mb-1 ml-auto mr-0 mr-md-2 my-0 my-md-3" href="job" id="back" role="button"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-arrow-left"></i> Back</a>
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-xl-1 col-sm-1 mb-1 mr-0 mr-md-2 my-0 my-md-3">Save <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rd[0]->kodejobspesifik ?>">
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**The Sender Form Controller code**

```
public function save()
    {
        $idglobal = $this->input->post('idJobOrder');

        $data = array('jobnya' => $idglobal );

        $this->Model_joborder->save_pg($data,'lapharian');
        redirect('progres_material');
    }
```

**The Config Routes code**

```
$route['progres_save']['get']='error';
$route['progres_save']['post']='save';

$route['progres_material']['get']='matused';
$route['progres_material']['post']='error';
```

**The Recipient Form Controller code**

```
public function matused()
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        $data['rd'] = $this->Model_joborder->tampil2($id);
        $data['fb'] = $this->Model_joborder->data_cbb();
        $this->load->view('matused', $data);
    }
```

**The Recipient Form View code**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= base_url().'matsave'; ?>">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-row">
         <?php if (isset($rd[0])) {?>
         <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rd[0]->jobspesifiknya; ?>" name="idClient" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" readonly>                  
         <?php } ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

What I expect is the input `id` value from Sender will be passed and catch on Recipient form as input `idClient`. Can anyone her help me to find out the solution? Thank you.

Comment: "input id value from Sender will be passed and catch on Recipient form" Can you explain a bit more? How do you mean pass to recipient?

Comment: @StefanAvramovic In Sender form, there is an input named `id` which has 1 as the value, then I want to pass that value into Recipient form.

Comment: Like a chat or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP global variable `$_REQUEST` to capture the data if you are not sure about the request type like this,

```
public function matused()
    {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $data['rd'] = $this->Model_joborder->tampil2($id);
        $data['fb'] = $this->Model_joborder->data_cbb();
        $this->load->view('matused', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the `id` data on the redirect after the `save()` method is called, so you will not get anything by calling `$this->input->get('id')`.

To solve this, pass the `id` data along with the redirect :

```
redirect('progres_material?id=' . $this->input->post('id'));
```

But that of course it will gives you an extra parameter on the url. If you don't want additional parameter, you could alternatively use session to pass `id` data while redirecting, on CodeIgniter there is a method called `set_flashdata` to do this :

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('id', $this->input->post('id'));
redirect('progres_material');
```

And to get the `id` session data on the `matused()` method, use the following code :

```
$id = !empty($this->session->flashdata('id')) ? $this->session->flashdata('id') : $this->input->get('id');
```